# Is there a way to deactivate specific rules of checkdoc?

Tags: checkdoc

To run [checkdoc](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CheckDoc) in a CI build it would be helpful to be able to tell `checkdoc` to deactivate some rules, either for a specific code passage through some comment (ignore a rule violation only for this specific line / function / file) or to deactivate certain rules for a whole file / a call to `checkdoc-file`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control the behavior of checkdoc to some extent by customizing some flags that it exposes using defcustom.  To see what's available, do <kbd>M-x customize-group checkdoc</kbd>.  In your case, you might want to change these values using elisp.  The defcustom variables available are:

- checkdoc-bouncy-flag
- checkdoc-force-docstrings-flag
- checkdoc-force-history-flag
- checkdoc-permit-comma-termination-flag
- checkdoc-spellcheck-documentation-flag
- checkdoc-max-keyref-before-warn
- checkdoc-arguments-in-order-flag
- checkdoc-package-keywords-flag
- checkdoc-verb-check-experimental-flag
- checkdoc-symbol-words
- checkdoc-column-zero-backslash-before-paren

They all seem to be boolean flags, and I'd use [`setq-local`](https://emacsdocs.org/docs/elisp/Creating-Buffer_002dLocal#macro-setq-local-rest-pairs) to give them temporary buffer-local values before calling `checkdoc` on a buffer.

```lisp
(setq-local checkdoc-force-docstrings-flag nil)
```

I don't know if this is enough control, but that's all I see available.

Comment: Thank you, great answer!
I found three more private flags in the source code: https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/155ddde4dd3f6246814ab76bc2f54f4d571bbd15/lisp/emacs-lisp/checkdoc.el#L342-L361